# Error, temporary mailbox in the account of Office 2010

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook-2010

I'm having a persistent error with a Office 365 account in Outlook 2010.

Each time I start the App, a prompt shows up telling me that could not synchronize the mailbox, and he let me choose between the old files data and the temporaly mailbox.

Office is up to date, I used the Microsoft Office365 configuration program and everything is configured and uptodate.

I reinstalled the whole Office 2010 App, installed the SP2 and made a new profile, none of those options worked.

***SOLVED***

The problem was caused by the corrupted profile of the user on Windows 7, 
After deleting the profile and recreate it, Outlook worked correctly

Comment: Could you write an answer and mark it as "answered" so that future users may use this.

Comment: Of course, I'm doing it right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***SOLVED***

The problem was caused by the corrupted profile of the user in Windows 7, After deleting the domain profile and recreate it, Outlook worked correctly.

Comment: were you able to find out what was corrupt with the profile? I am curious. and what lead you to trying that?

Comment: After trying everything, I tried the same configuration inside a VMware system, in that system everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

backup your local email.

Delete your email account connection locally.

Manually set up a new email connection to 365 [here are some instructions](https://itservices.usc.edu/office365/emailclients/)

see if this fixes the issue.

If it does not then your old mailbox file might be corrupt. you will need to move the old mailbox file and create a blank new one. depending on how you are connecting to 365 this could either be a pst if it is imap or pop or an ost if it is exchange. Backup your old file and in the email connection settings there should be a spot to change the database file it is using. Tell it to use a new one.

[here is instructions on creating a new OST file](https://kb.intermedia.net/article/1079) it will take a bit of time to resync depending on how many emails you have and make sure to do a [backup of your emails first](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Export-or-backup-email-contacts-and-calendar-to-an-Outlook-pst-file-14252b52-3075-4e9b-be4e-ff9ef1068f91) just incase anything strange happens.

[here is some information on ost and pst files](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-an-Outlook-Data-File-pst-to-save-your-information-17a13ca2-df52-48e8-b933-4c84c2aabe7c)

Comment: why the downvotes? especially without comments? The OP probably has a corrupt OST file. I cannot give them the location of their ost file since it could be placed anywhere they want.

Comment: "I reinstalled the whole Office 2010 App, installed the SP2 and made a new profile, none of those options worked."